# Powershell renaming multiple server names

Tags: powershell, replace

I recently got the answer to get the friendly name of Windows servers, for example, Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, and I wanted to remove "Windows Server", here is the code that does this correctly:

```
$Build = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computername $Computer | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Caption) -replace "Microsoft Windows Server ",""
```

However,  I have discovered that Windows 2003 have a slightly different naming convention:

```
Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003, Standard Edition.
```

So I want the script to remove "Microsoft(R) Windows(R) " if this is the case. I tried adding `-or -replace "Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server ",""` but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `RegEx`'s OR operator (`|`) to match two words to be replaced.

```
-replace [Regex]"Microsoft Windows Server |Microsoft\(R\) Windows\(R\) ",""
```

Or you can simple just use another `-replace` after the first -replace.

```
-replace "Microsoft Windows Server ","" -replace "Microsoft\(R\) Windows\(R\) ",""
```

**Note:** You need to escape brackets for them to be replaced e.g. `\(` & `\)`